How to apply filters with custom routes and many filters with API platform
I try to apply filters With Symfony 6 + API platform 3 with custom route, but only pagination is applied. The standard route is working well.
My actual code:
Entity:
#[ORM\Table(name: 'stb_maxi_dev.offer_demand')]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(),
        new Get(),
        new Post(),
        new Patch(),
        new GetCollection(
            name: 'api_export_offers',
            controller: OfferController::class,
            output: false
        )
    ],
    routePrefix: '/maxi',
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['offers:list', 'status:list', 'source:list', 'tn:list', 'as:list', 'country:list', 'category:list', 'product:list', 'logs:list']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['offers:write']],
    paginationEnabled: false
)]
#[ApiFilter(NumericFilter::class, properties: ['od_status'])]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: [
    'od_source.id' => 'exact',
    'od_country.id' => 'exact',
    'od_category.id' => 'exact',
    'od_activity_sector.id' => 'exact',
    'od_product.id' => 'exact',
    'od_team.id' => 'exact',
    'od_offer_status.id' => 'exact',
    'od_rfq_status.id' => 'exact',
])]
#[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties: ['od_creation_date', 'receivedAt', 'od_date_acknowledgment_receipt', 'date_conctacting'])]
#[ApiFilter(GroupFilter::class, arguments: ['overrideDefaultGroups' => false])]

class OfferController extends AbstractController
{
    private $collectionProvider;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(CollectionProvider $collectionProvider, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->collectionProvider = $collectionProvider;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    #[Route('/maxi/offers/export', name: 'api_export_offers', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function exportOffers(Request $request, Utils $utils)
    {
        $filters = $request->query->all();

        $operation = new GetCollection(class: OfferDemand::class);

        $offerdemands = $this->collectionProvider->provide($operation, [], ['filters' => $filters]);
    
      // CODE TO EXPORT IN XSLX
      return $this->file($temp_file, $fileName, ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);

    }
}

Is it possible to apply all filters like standard API platform collection endpoint?
